# make error occured in gcc c++ compiler with mingw linker

Tags: gcc, g++, eclipse-cdt

Build of configuration Release for project testcase

```
make all 
Building file: ../atest.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I"C:\cppunit\include" -I"C:\cppunit\include\cppunit\extensions" -I"C:\mingw\bin" -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0, -Wl,-subsystem,console -MMD -MP -MF"atest.d" -MT"atest.d" -o"atest.o" "../atest.cpp"
cc1plus.exe: error: argument to "-fmessage-length=" should be a non-negative integer
make: *** [atest.o] Error 1
```

actually in my  gcc c++ compller has -c -fmessage-length=0 this flag has been given but my in console window showing above error

Comment: Haha, weird error... Nice and helpful. What happens when you set the value to 1? Just for fun...

Comment: Oh, also, should there be a comma after the 0?

Comment: It doesn't change the compiled executable, try removing the -fmessage-length argument altogether. Also, what version of gcc are you using.

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually a make error.  make runs other commands (such as g++) to actually build the project.  When one of those commands gives an error, make will stop (unless specifically told to ignore the error).

This appears to be a bug in mingw compiler.  I've tried `-fmessage-length=0` on multiple versions of g++ (4.2.1 for Darwin/Mac, 4.3.2 on Linux) and none of them issued that error (and I could create the error by specifying `-fmessage-length=-1`).

Answer (score 0):

Remove trailing comma from `-fmessage-length=0,`